# How to determine which AWS regions are being used by various accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations, aws-regions

## Overview

Within our AWS Organization, we have various AWS accounts and across all of those accounts want to understand which teams are leveraging services in which regions within each account.

Does anyone know of a way to pull this kind of breakdown? CLI, SDK, Console, etc?

## Additional information

I am interested in not just whether or not a region is enabled or not, but additionally if it is being actively leveraged, and ideally what services are being used within it (paid and free). We have received advice to look in **AWS Cost Explorer** to determine which services are being leveraged, however, it only includes results for paid services and not free ones such as **IAM**.

A standard set of regions is enabled by default, however, teams may not be actively using any of those regions.

Comment: Have you tried using SQL to query CloudTrail logs in Athena?

Comment: Seems like one option might be "Viewing Service Last Accessed Data for Organizations" - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_access-advisor-view-data-orgs.html - data can be pulled in console, CLI or API.

Answer (score 0):

You’d need to use CloudTrail to determine this. Setup a trail to an s3 bucket and then use Athena to retrieve the information you’re looking for.

Couple of points of note

- Some services are global so will turn up as us-east-1
- For S3 or Lambda operations you will need to enable for the trail, beware though that this may create large volumes of noise depending on your usage

Answer (score 0):

To get a high level overview of usage, I always find it easiest to go to the Billing Dashboard and look at the bill for the current month. It updates every couple of hours and provides a nice breakdown between services and regions. It also records services that have a free tier (such as lambda). If you have multiple accounts linked then you can easily break down per account as well. Then to dig deeper, go to the specific service in a region to see exactly what is there.